# How can I make 'Split' and 'wordCount' methods work together?

Tags: java, split, word-count

I am a beginner in java, first year computing student with very weak understanding of java and many problems with understanding its structures.

This is my code I have so far:

```
         import java.util.*;

public class hdtest1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);       
String s;
while(true)  
{
    System.out.println("Enter value:");
    s=sc.next();    
    if(s.equals("quit"))                  
    {
        break;
    }
  String[] s = string.split(" ");
   int wordCount = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) 
{
    if (str1.charAt(i) == ' '&& str1.charAt(i+1)!=' ') 
    {
        wordCount++;
    } 
}
 }

 }
    System.out.println(""+s); //to Print string
    System.out.println(""+s.length());  //to print Entered string's length
    System.out.println("Word count is = " +(str1.length()- wordCount));


}
```

I would like my java output to show the text line entered in the text window (scanner), total number of characters and the number of characters for each word. For example when the user enters 'Hello, my name is Mark', the output I am looking for is:

```
      Hello, my name is Mark
      22
      Hello = 5
      my = 2
      name = 4
      is = 2
      Mark = 4
      //Here the scanner loops,appears and is ready for more text to be entered
```

So to sum up my question - Please could you correct my code where the errors are to make it work correctly and output what I want (shown above)? Thank you very much for your help, any help would be much appreciated.

At the moment my code displays many errors, they are the structural errors because I have very weak understanding of matching different methods together. So far I found many chunks of code which I thought would work together and I've tried to manipulate with the code to make the methods work together, but I only seem to make my code worse as I don't understand the meaning of many errors to be able to correct them. My code worked fine until i started trying to split the words entered in the scanner by using the method 'split'.

Here is a quick list of errors for you to have a look:

line 15 - duplicate variable s,

line 15 - string cannot be resolved,

line 18 - str1 cannot be resolved,

line 20 -  str1 cannot be resolved,

line 28 - syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct (s),

line 28 - syntax error on token "println", = expected after this token,

line 29 - syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct (s),

line 30 - syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct (s),

line 30 - syntax error on token "println", = expected after this token,

Comment: What is it, specifically, about the error messages you're having trouble with? For instance, let's look at the first error message: *"duplicate variable s"* What about that error is unclear? You have `String s;` in one place and then `String[] s = string.split(" ");` in a second place (line 15). Each of those is a *variable declaration* (the second one also has an initializer). You can't declare a variable twice within the same scope.

Comment: Begin with the first error message. Read it. Think about it. Search for it. If you can work out how to fix it, do so. If not, write a specific question about that message, saying what steps you have taken to understand it. Repeat as needed.

Comment: It tells you the line numbers, so that should be a big help. "Cannot be resolved" means there's no variable with that name. The syntax errors are a little tricky, but if you fix your indentation, it might become clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split a sentence into constituent words and then simply call length() method on each word to get the number of characters.

```
String[] words = input.split("\\s+");  // get the individual words (separated by white space)
System.out("#words = " + words.length);
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    System.out("word[" + i + "]: " + words[i] + " nchars = " + words[i].length());
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want this:

```
int wordCount = string.split(" ").length;
```

If you want to print words and their lengths:

```
for (String word : string.split(" "))
    System.out.println(word + " = " + word.length());
```

Comment: Well, this _does_ answer the question posed in the title, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have input from the scanner (say it's a variable called `input`), try:

```
// The line below splits the sentence into individual tokens by spaces, and puts them into an array
String[] allWords = input.split(" "); 
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(input.length()); // Get number of characters in input
for (int i = 0; i < allWords.length; i++) { // Loop through each word
    String word = allWords[i].replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""); // This uses a regex to eliminate anything but letters and puts the word into a variable "word"
    System.out.println(word + " = " + word.length()); // Output the word and the length
}
```

Put this block of code in a loop where the scanner reads a line.

Just a note, the length() method outputs the number of characters in a string, including spaces. That's why we remove all other characters besides letters when we output the length.

Comment: OP needs to learn how to debug, not learn how to get strangers on the internet to do his/her homework for him/her.

Comment: Very true, but sometimes having an exact example code is a great way to learn. I tried to comment every line so that OP can know exactly what is happening

Comment: You're right, of course. I just have known too many students, and worse, too many professionals, who manage to scrape by while attempting to minimize activities like "research" and "analysis".

Answer (score 1):

Couple pointers:

1. You have a String s and a String[] s, you can't do that, rename one of them.
2. Where is "str1"? It hasn't been declared or initialized.

3.

```
    System.out.println(""+s);
```

"s" is already a String, ""+ is unnecessary.